# Trying to match a partial name of file in text of file + additional text

Tags: regex, perl, match

Hi I'm trying to match a partial name of file in text of file + additional text.

Basically I've got files named something like this:

```
PieceIwanttomatch_don't_care_about_this.txt
```

and I'm trying the match the first say seven letters of the file name plus a string in the file and I'm not having any luck.

Here's what I have so far:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Path qw(make_path remove_tree);

my $calls_dir = "Ask/Parsed/Html/";
opendir(my $search_dir, $calls_dir) or die "$!\n";
my @files = grep /\.txt$/i, readdir $search_dir;
closedir $search_dir;

#print "Got ", scalar @files, " files\n";

#my %seen = ();
for my $file (@files) {

  my %seen         = ();
  my $current_file = $calls_dir . $file;
  open my $FILE, '<', $current_file or die "$file: $!\n";

  while (<$FILE>) {

    #if (/phone/i) {
    chomp;

    #if (/phone\s*(.*)\r?$/i) {
    #if (/^phone\s*:\s*(.*)\r?$/i) {
    #if (/Contact\s*(.*)\r?$/i) {
    #if (/^*(.*)team\s*(.*)\r?$/i) {

    print substr(${file}, 0, 7);

    if (/^(?=.* 'substr(${file}, 0, 7)')(?=.*management)/s) {

      $seen{$1} = 1;

      #print $file."\t"."$_\n";
      #open my $fh, '>', "Ask/Parsed/Html2/"."${file}.parsed_for_contact_us.txt" or die $!;

      make_path('Ask/Parsed/Html2/');
      open my $fh, '>', "Ask/Parsed/Html2/" . "${file}.parsed_for_management.txt" or die $!;
      #open my $fh, '>', "$_"."result".".txt" or die $!;

      #$fh->print("$file\t$_\n");
      $fh->print("$_\n");
      print "$_\n";

      #print "\t";
      print "\n";
      print "\t";

      #print "$_\n";
      #print "\t";
      #print "\n";

      foreach my $addr (sort keys %seen) {

      }
    }
  }

  close $FILE;
}
```

Here's another example for people to look at:

## I think an example of what I'm trying to do: say my file is named `nintendo_ask_parse.html`.  I'm trying to use the string `nintendo` from the file name together with another string, say `game`, to find a line in the file and print it to another file.

added 11-12-2014
Here's some more data as requested by a few who have kindly been helping me so far.  I'm running this first script that I wrote to pull URLs into files.  Here's the script:

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use LWP::Simple;

 my $link1 = "http://www.ask.com/web?q=";
 my $link2 = "+video+game&qsrc=0&o=0&l=dir&qo=homepageSearchBox";
 #my $link3 = "http://www.";
 #my $link4 = "http://www.manta.com/search?          search_source=nav&pt=&search_location=Burlingame+CA&search=";

 open (my $fh2, "untitled.txt")
 or die "Could not open file";

 while (my $row = <$fh2>) {
 chomp $row;
 print "$row\n";
 my $xml1 = $link1 . $row. $link2 ;
 #my $xmla = $link3 . $row . ".com";
 #my $xmlx = $link4 . $row;
 mkdir 'Ask', 0755;
 my $filename1 = "Ask/".($row)."_"."ask".".html";
 open my $fh1, ">", $filename1 or die("Could not open file. $!");

 print $row;
 my $xml2 = get $xml1;
 print $xml1;
 print "\n";
 print $fh1 $xml2;


 }
```

=============================================================================
After this script runs I get html files based on the # of entries in my untitled.txt file, 1 per entry.

## I have four example files, they are named Activision_ask.html, Apple_ask.html, Atari_ask.html, Nintendo_ask.html from running the script above.  Here are the contents one file Activion_ask.html:

```
     Answers
     Q&A Community
     Advanced Search


     Everything
     Images
     News
     First Video Game Invented
     Video Game Design
     Wii
     Video Game Designer Career
     Video Game Companies
     Spider-man 3 Video Game
     Video Game Walkthroughs
     Video Game Statistics
     Call of Duty 4
     More Answers
     Amazon.com results for activision


     Source
     Activision Publishing, Inc. is an American video game publisher. It was founded on October 1,      1979 and was the world's first independent developer and distributor of video games for gaming   consoles. Its first products were cartridges for the Atari 2600 video console system published from July 1980 for the US market and from August 1981 for the international market (UK). Activision is now one of the largest video game publishers in the world and was also the top publisher for 2... Read More »
Go to: Ask Encyclopedia · Images · Videos
Browse Article: History · Studios · Notable games published · Upcoming games · References ·
Source: Wikipedia
Related Questions:
     •
     Who was the Video game publisher of LOOM?
     •
     Who is developing the games for Activision and what have they done in the past? We hear the  handheld versions of the game are different than the console versions. Care to enlighten us?
     •
     This game was created by "Activision" for the "Atari 2600". Up to four players could play at one time. Which one was it?
     View more Q&A »

     www.giantbomb.com/activision/3010-78/

     Oct 9, 2014 ... Activision is the largest third-party publisher in the world. It became the first third- party developer for video game consoles, and is responsible ...

      Explore More Answers About

     Source: www.kgbanswers.com

     About · Privacy · Terms · Careers · Ask Blog · Q&A · Mobile · Help · Feedback © 2014 Ask.com
     **truncated
```

=============================================================================

There's a second script that pulls out all of the links from the html file above and puts it into another file.  Here's that script:

=============================================================================

```
  use lib '/Users/lialin/perl5/lib/perl5';
          use strict; use warnings;
          use feature 'say';
     use File::Slurp 'slurp';  # makes it

 easy to read files.
     use Mojo;
     use Mojo::UserAgent;
     use URI;
     use File::Path qw(make_path remove_tree);


     #my $html_file = shift @ARGV; # take file from command lin

     my $calls_dir = "Ask/";
     opendir(my $search_dir, $calls_dir) or die "$!\n";
     my @html_files = grep /\.html$/i, readdir $search_dir;
     closedir $search_dir;
     #print "Got ", scalar @files, " files\n";

     #my %seen = ();
     foreach my $html_files (@html_files) {
        my %seen = ();
        my $current_file = $calls_dir . $html_files;
        open my $FILE, '<', $current_file or die "$html_files: $!\n";

     my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new(scalar slurp $calls_dir .$html_files);
     print $calls_dir .$html_files ;

     #for my $csshref ($dom->find('a[href]')->attr('href')->each) {
     #for my $link ($dom->find('a[href]')->attr('href')->each) {
     #  print $1;
     #say $1 #if $link->attr('href') =~ m{^https?://(.+?)/index\.php}s;
     make_path('Ask/Parsed/Html/');
     open my $fh, '>', "Ask/Parsed/Html/${html_files}.result.txt" or die $!;
     for my $csshref ($dom->find('a[href]')->attr('href')->each) {
     my $cssurl = URI->new($csshref)->abs($calls_dir .$html_files);

     #open my $fh, '>', "Ask/${html_files}.result.txt" or die $!;
     $fh->print("$html_files\n");
     $fh->print("$cssurl\n");
     #$fh->print("\t"."$_\n");
     #print "$cssurl\n";
     #print $file."\t"."$_\n";}}
```

====================================================

The resulting files look like this (using Activision as an example again):

=============================================================================

```
    Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/answers/browse?     qsrc=167&q=Activision+video+game&qo=channelNavigation&o=0&l=dir
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/answers/browse?qsrc=167&q=Activision+video+game&o=0&l=dir#opensignin
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/answers/profile?qsrc=3099
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/answers/profile?qsrc=3099
     Activision_ask.html
     javascript:void(0);
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/advancedsearch?     qsrc=167&q=Activision+video+game&qo=channelNavigation&o=0&l=dir
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/?o=0&l=dir&qsrc=14137
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/pictures?q=Activision+video+game&qsrc=167&qo=channelNavigation&o=0&l=dir
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/news?q=Activision+video+game&qsrc=167&qo=channelNavigation&o=0&l=dir
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/youtube?q=Activision+video+game&qsrc=167&qo=channelNavigation&o=0&l=dir
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/shopping?q=Activision+video+game&qsrc=167&qo=channelNavigation&o=0&l=dir
     Activision_ask.html
     javascript:void(0);
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/maps?q=Activision+video+game&qsrc=167&qo=channelNavigation&o=0&l=dir
     Activision_ask.html
     javascript:void(0);
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/web?q=Video+Game+Cheats&qsrc=466&o=0&l=dir&qo=relatedSearchNarrow
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/web?q=Video+Game+Tester&qsrc=466&o=0&l=dir&qo=relatedSearchNarrow
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/web?q=Create+Your+Own+Video+Games&qsrc=466&o=0&l=dir&qo=relatedSearchNarrow
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/web?q=First+Video+Game+Invented&qsrc=466&o=0&l=dir&qo=relatedSearchNarrow
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/web?q=Video+Game+Design&qsrc=466&o=0&l=dir&qo=relatedSearchNarrow
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/web?q=Wii&qsrc=466&o=0&l=dir&qo=relatedSearchExpand
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/web?q=Video+Game+Designer+Career&qsrc=466&o=0&l=dir&qo=relatedSearchNarrow
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/web?q=Video+Game+Companies&qsrc=466&o=0&l=dir&qo=relatedSearchNarrow
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/web?q=Spider-man+3+Video+Game&qsrc=466&o=0&l=dir&qo=relatedSearchNarrow
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/web?q=Video+Game+Walkthroughs&qsrc=466&o=0&l=dir&qo=relatedSearchNarrow
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/web?q=Video+Game+Statistics&qsrc=466&o=0&l=dir&qo=relatedSearchNarrow
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/web?q=Call+of+Duty+4&qsrc=466&o=0&l=dir&qo=relatedSearchExpand
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_ss_gw?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-     keywords=activision&x=0&y=0&tag=askcom05-20
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.amazon.com/Activision-Anthology-PlayStation-  2/dp/B00006Z7HQ%3Fpsc%3D1%26SubscriptionId%3D06KMPSHEDSXXQMQVT482%26tag%3Daskcom05-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB00006Z7HQ
Activision_ask.html
http://www.amazon.com/Activision-Anthology-PlayStation-2/dp/B00006Z7HQ%3Fpsc%3D1%26SubscriptionId%3D06KMPSHEDSXXQMQVT482%26tag%3Daskcom05-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB00006Z7HQ
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.amazon.com/Destiny-Xbox-360/dp/B002I096Q4%3Fpsc%3D1%26SubscriptionId%3D06KMPSHEDSXXQMQVT482%26tag%3Daskcom05-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB002I096Q4
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.amazon.com/Destiny-Xbox-360/dp/B002I096Q4%3Fpsc%3D1%26SubscriptionId%3D06KMPSHEDSXXQMQVT482%26tag%3Daskcom05-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB002I096Q4
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.amazon.com/Skylanders-Trap-Team-Not-Machine-Specific/dp/B00NCA6ZT0%3Fpsc%3D1%26SubscriptionId%3D06KMPSHEDSXXQMQVT482%26tag%3Daskcom05-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB00NCA6ZT0
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.amazon.com/Skylanders-Trap-Team-Not-Machine-Specific/dp/B00NCA6ZT0%3Fpsc%3D1%26SubscriptionId%3D06KMPSHEDSXXQMQVT482%26tag%3Daskcom05-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB00NCA6ZT0
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_ss_gw?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=activision&x=0&y=0&tag=askcom05-20
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/wiki/Activision
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/wiki/Activision
     Activision_ask.html
     http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Activision.svg
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/allabout?q=video%20game%20publisher&qsrc=470
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/allabout?q=video%20game%20console&qsrc=470
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/allabout?q=Atari%202600&qsrc=470
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/wiki/Activision
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/wiki/Activision#Upcoming_games
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/wiki/Activision#References
     Activision_ask.html
     http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activision
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/web?q=Who+was+the+Video+game+publisher+of+LOOM%3F&qsrc=469&o=0&l=dir&qo=relatedQuestions
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/web?q=Activision+video+game&qsrc=3060&o=0&l=dir
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.activision.com/
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.activision.com/games
     Activision_ask.html
     http://clk.about.com?zi=13/1tO&ity=boostOrg&o=0&ldid=4451&eng=boost&zu=http://vgstrategies.about.com/od/gameboycheatscodes/a/Activision-Anthology.htm
     http://www.gametrailers.com/company/pou3yf/activision
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.cnbc.com/id/102026893
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.giantbomb.com/activision/3010-78/
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/web?q=History+of+Video+Game+Systems&qsrc=467&o=0&l=dir&qo=relatedSearchNarrow
     Activision_ask.html
     http://www.ask.com/mobile?&o=0&l=dir&qsrc=0
     Activision_ask.html
     http://help.ask.com
     Activision_ask.html
     http://feedback.ask.com
```

=============================================================================
Now I'm working on a final script that will use part the name of a file and a string to read a line or multiple lines from a file that contain matching or close to matching text.

In the above example I am interested in 'http://www.activision.com/games' or basically any URL with the word 'Activision' from the file name and the word 'game' in it.

My file names obviously very in size and the word game may come before or after the file name.

I hope the explanation and code helps others understand what I am trying to accomplish.

The problem I have right now is the the regex command for searching for the strings.  I'm working on making it less strict and can't get the matching to work properly.

As I mentioned before I'm pretty well versed in html and java but I know that perl is the right language to this in and am obviously not an expert (if you look at my code above) but trying to learn and complete my task.

Comment: You would find it much easier to work with your code if you indented it properly and added blank lines between chunks of related statements. I've done it for you here (all I've added is whitespace).

Comment: The regex match you're talking about is presumably `/^(?=.* 'substr(${file}, 0, 7)')(?=.*management)/s` but I can't see what it's supposed to do as you're not comparing the first seven characters to anything else.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear what it is you want to do, but given your example file name

```
PieceIwanttomatch_don't_care_about_this.txt
```

suppose you want to find all files with those first seven characters `PieceIw` that also end with `.txt` you would write

```
if ( /^PieceIw.*\.txt$/ ) { ... }
```

I hope that helps

---

**Update**

Okay what I *think* you want is to search all `.txt` files in a directory for lines that contain the first N characters of the file name as well as some other specified string.

If you don't know which will appear first -- the file name prefix or the other string -- then you were along the right lines with your double look-ahead. One refinement would be to enclose the strings in `\Q...\E` which escapes all non-word characters to prevent any regex metacharacters from messing up the pattern.

Note also the following

- I've used `autodie`, as I explained in my answer to your previous question. If you're running a version of Perl earlier than v5.10 and you can't upgrade then you won't be able to do this and will have to check the status of each file operation separately
- It's important to use *absolute* paths for the directories; otherwise the user has to make sure they have the correct current working directory before running the program
- I've put all the parameters to the program -- the two directories and the additional string to be searched for - as definitions at the top of the program
- I've used `glob` instead of `opendir` / `readdir` / `grep` because it's tidier, and so that the file names include the full path

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

use File::Path qw/ make_path remove_tree /;
use File::Basename qw/ fileparse /;

my $calls_dir  = '/path/to/Ask/Parsed/Html';
my $parsed_dir = '/path/to/Ask/Parsed/Html2';
my $wanted     = 'game';

my @files = glob "$calls_dir/*.txt";

printf "Got %d files\n", scalar @files;

for my $file (@files) {

  open my $in_fh, '<', $file;

  my $prefix = substr $file, 0, 8;
  print $prefix, "\n";

  my $basename = fileparse($file);
  make_path($parsed_dir);
  open my $out_fh, '>', "$parsed_dir/${basename}_parsed_for_management.txt";

  while (<$in_fh>) {
    print $out_fh $_ if / \Q$prefix\E .* \Q$wanted\E /x;
  }

  close $out_fh;
}
```

---

**Update**

This works fine

```
my ($wanted, $prefix) = qw/ game nintendo /;

for ( 'game.nintendo.com/phoenix.zhtml?c=121127&p=irol-gom' ) {
  print "OK\n" if / \Q$wanted\E .* \Q$prefix\E /x;
}
```

**output**

```
OK
```

Comment: Thanks Borodin.  I think an example of what I'm trying to do: say my file is named nintendo_ask_parse.html.  I'm trying to use the string "nintendo" + another string "game" to find a line in the file and print it to another file.

Comment: So the code almost works.  Could be the user.  My first issue is that $file returns not only the file name but the entire path+file name.  $prefix always returns 1.  Because $file returns the entire path+file name the write fails.  Did some printing of variables to figure this out.  Any ideas for modification are appreciated.

Comment: Incidentally the prefix will always come before the wanted in the line to return.

Comment: @tlialin: Sorry, I couldn't easily test my code except to make sure that it would compile. Try now.

Comment: Better.  I modified it this way my ($prefix) = $basename =~ /^(.{6})/; and got the file characters that I was looking for, awesome!  But I don't get anything written in the output.  I was wrong on order so I changed to this push @matches, $_ if / \Q$wanted\E .* \Q$prefix\E /x; but I'm still not returning any matches.  Here's an example of the line that I'm trying to return : http://game.nintendo.com/phoenix.zhtml?c=121127&p=irol-gom from the file.  It looks like it should match $wanted and $prefix.  Do we need to be looser with the regex?  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @tlialin: That line is matched fine. I've added a demo to my solution. There must be something else wrong with your code. You seem to have an intermediate copy of my solution; can you try the latest one please?

Comment: The name that I'm pulling back from the file is not a regular size.  Sometimes it's 6 characters, sometimes 10, etc.  Could that be breaking the match?  Is there a way to search for the first 6 characters of the filename, accept some garbage in between and then the other string?  After closer inspection it also seems the format is not always filename.string, it's sometimes string.filename.  Thanks - Tony

Comment: Just also saw that the File Names are also Capitalized so it's Nintendo not nintendo.  Is there a way to account for upper of lower case and accept if either in the regex?

Comment: Checked to see if I have all of your new code and the answer is yes.  Thanks again for the assistance here, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Well yes, of course it would break the match. But when you say you want to match the first N characters of the file name and *"the prefix will always come before the wanted"* I have no choice but to believe you. If you are wrong then my solution will be wrong. Do you not know any Perl *at all*? I would have hoped that you could use my answer as a basis for a solution to the *real* situation, but you seem to be floundering without any idea of where to go next. Stack Overflow ***is not*** a place to come to for free programming work. If you have any skills at all then please show them.

Comment: You appear to be starting with some code that *almost* works for you, and hoping to [monkey-patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) to get it closer. 
Code is either bug-free and working or simply wrong, so your comments like *"So the code almost works. Could be the user"* and *"Better. I modified it this way"* show a bizarre misunderstanding of the way debugging works.

Comment: What is missing is a proper analysis of the problem, and an educated guess about the form a solution may take. If you show us the real data then I am certain that we could swiftly make a first pass and give you some working code

Comment: I'm not looking for free programming work.  I'm a molecular biologist by training with some fairly good html and java programming skills.  I did a start up where all of our code was in perl Tk and therefore have some perl knowledge but am not as good in perl and I am the other two languages.  Trying to help a friend with a project he has.  I'll post some examples.  Sorry I didn't notice the exceptions earlier.

Comment: @tialin: I can see from the question you have posted that you are far from being *"fairly good"* with either HTML or Java. Your Perl is abysmal and you really shouldn't offer to help *anyone* with your guidance. I certainly wouldn't risk my friendships by offering such dreadful advice.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat speculative, trying to read between the lines here.

```
opendir(my $search_dir, $calls_dir) or die "$!\n";
my @files = grep /^${prefix}_/ grep /\.txt$/i, readdir $search_dir;
closedir $search_dir;
```

Now `@files` contains only the `.txt` files whose name starts with `$prefix` followed by an underscore.  You don't want to search through any other files than these.  I'm speculating on the underscore but you can probably modify it to better suit your needs if that's not exactly it.

Now, search (only) those files for a match.

```
for my $file (@files) {
  my $current_file = $calls_dir . $file;
  open my $FILE, '<', $current_file or die "$file: $!\n";    
  while (<$FILE>) {
      print "$file\n$" if m/management/;
  }
}
```

I would actually suggest to use a tab or colon delimiter instead of a newline between the file name and the matching line.  Line-oriented output is so much easier to use.

Of course, all of this is just

```
grep management "$prefix"_*.txt >output
```

in one line of shell script.